# How to produce 1 output with multiple input variables LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to predict the opening price for the next day. I'm able to get the formatting correct to feed in the input i.e. ('Open','High' columns per day for n time). However when I format into a 3D array my shape is as follows:

```
(1200, 60, 2)
```

The X_train has 1200 samples, with 60 timestep (previous 60 days of historical data) and 2 features (open and high)

However, My issue arises when its reaches the keras coding part when implementing layers. This is my code I am using:

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 2)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))
```

The problem arises with the last line. I want the output to be only 1. So essentially I want the Open and High values of the input series to be used to work out the final singular output of just the Open price. However, by setting the `Dense(units = 1)`, creates this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

To fix this I have tried to change it to 2 `Dense(units=2)`, however the final output produces 2 lines on the graph one for open and one for high which is not what I want. That's 2 outputs where I want 1. I'm not sure what to do with this scenario.

**regressor.summary()**

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 60, 50)            10600     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 60, 50)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 60, 50)            20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 60, 50)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 60, 50)            20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 60, 50)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 50)                20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 102       
=================================================================
Total params: 71,302
Trainable params: 71,302
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Im not sure why Dense(2) works and not Dense(1); however if your getting 2 outputs why not just take the one you need, the `open` in this case. Check the shape before you apply Dense

Comment: @Kenan Because the Dense 1 is expecting one output (which is open) but the layers are holding 2 (open,close). The issue I'm having is I want to use the open an high to work out the open at t + 1 onwards. I can't figure out how to create the dataframe to pass through the Neural Network.

Comment: can you show `regressor.summary()`

Comment: @Kenan I have updated the post to show the summary

Comment: what's your `Y_train.shape`?

Comment: @Kenan ```(1200, 2)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206949/discussion-between-kenan-and-user218030).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the dense layer is having a shape error it might be your label tensor that is not matching. Check that `y_train` has shape [1200, 1] so that you can use a dense of 1.